# Scale Text To Exact Pixel Height

Tags: html, css, fonts

**Question**: Is there any way - using plain old css/html/js (ideally without requiring a canvas, svg, or images) - to adjust the *visual* size of an uppercase letter to an exact pixel height?

**Current Approach**: define a span element containing the text/character, and adjust it's css using `transform: scale(x,y)`. The problem here is that in doing so, while the span height adjusts perfectly the text within contains whitespace on the top/bottom (ascent/descent?) that prevents it from 'filling' the span itself. An example of this is below, attempting to scale a letter to 5x vertically (the border added is meant to show whitespace on top/bottom of letter)

```css
.ms{
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: scale(1,5);
}
```

```html
<span class="ms">M</span>
```

FWIW I am attempting to create a 'sequence logo' using basic css/html, in which one or more characters are depicted with their heights proportional to frequency. I have had little success making adjustments to descent-override, ascent-override, or line-height

Comment: you could probably reset line-height to hold the letter , but it would be average from a letter to another. capitals should be even, but letters like atpfb will remain on their baseline and overflow at top or bottom. Courrier here would do with an average  line-height: 0.5725; for capitals